# How to resolve slow render appending to container?

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

I've set up a [jquery datatable](https://datatables.net/) which renders slowly when appending toolbar items to the the top of the table container.

What I've tried is getting the class of the container and just appending to that with jQuery during the [preInit event](https://datatables.net/reference/event/preInit). But this doesn't seem to be an efficient method at render:

```
       $("#escalation").one("preInit.dt", function (evtObj, settings) {

            var $newbtncontainer = $("<div class='dt-buttons'></div>");
            $("#escalation_wrapper").prepend($newbtncontainer);
            $("a.buttons-colvis").appendTo($newbtncontainer);
            $("#tblDateRange").appendTo($newbtncontainer);
        });
```

My table itself loads at a decent speed but the adding of toolbar items is really slow.

**Question:**

How can you resolve slow render when appending to datatable contianer?

This is the datatable markup and the jQuery to append the toolbar items:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-daterangepicker/2.1.24/daterangepicker.min.css" />

            <div class="table-responsive max-width-table" id="datatable-wrapper">
                <style>
                    #escalation tr > *:nth-child(1) {
                        display: none;
                    }
                </style>

                <div class="form-group form-inline pull-left" id="colFilter"></div>

                <div class="form-group form-inline pull-right" id="tblDateRange">
                    <label id="dateRangeLbl" class="date-range-label">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        <input class="input-sm top-buffer pull-right date-range-input" id="dateRangeInput" type="text" name="daterange" value="01/01/2016 - 12/25/2016" />
                    </label>
                </div>

                <div class="btn-group pull-right">

                    <button id="scrollXLeft-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span> </button>
                    <button id="scrollXRight-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span> </button>

                </div>



                <table id="escalation" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Fruit</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                       <tr>
                          <td>1</td>
                          <td>Apple</td>      
                       </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

    </div>





<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.1/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.18/build/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.18/build/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.1/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>



<script>


    //Once the Document DOM is ready..
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#scrollXRight-btn").click(function () {

            var leftPos = $('div.dataTables_scrollBody').scrollLeft();
            $("div.dataTables_scrollBody").animate({ scrollLeft: leftPos + 800 }, 800);

        });

        $("#scrollXLeft-btn").click(function () {

            var leftPos = $('div.dataTables_scrollBody').scrollLeft();
            $("div.dataTables_scrollBody").animate({ scrollLeft: leftPos - 800 }, 800);

        });


        $("#escalation").one("preInit.dt", function (evtObj, settings) {

            var $newbtncontainer = $("<div class='dt-buttons'></div>");
            $("#escalation_wrapper").prepend($newbtncontainer);
            $("a.buttons-colvis").appendTo($newbtncontainer);
            $("#tblDateRange").appendTo($newbtncontainer);
        });


        var historyTable = $('#escalation').DataTable({
            "order": [[1, "desc"]],
            colReorder: true,
            scrollY: 1000,
            scrollX: "100%",

        });



    });



</script>
```

Comment: You are appending the same button 3 different times?

Comment: @Bindrid Can you comment the code where you see that? My understanding is that this prepends the toolbar items to the dt-buttons div:  ` $("#escalation_wrapper").prepend($newbtncontainer);
            $("a.buttons-colvis").appendTo($newbtncontainer);
            $("#tblDateRange").appendTo($newbtncontainer);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  $("#escalation").one("preInit.dt", function (evtObj, settings) {

        var $newbtncontainer = $("<div class='dt-buttons'></div>");
        $("#escalation_wrapper").prepend($newbtncontainer);
        $("a.buttons-colvis").appendTo($newbtncontainer);
        $("#tblDateRange").appendTo($newbtncontainer);
    });($newbtncontainer);
```

should be

```
 $("#escalation").one("preInit.dt", function (evtObj, settings) {


        $("#escalation_wrapper").prepend( "<div class='dt-buttons'></div>"  );
        $("a.buttons-colvis").appendTo("<div class='dt-buttons'></div>");
        $("#tblDateRange").appendTo("<div class='dt-buttons'></div>" );
    });
```

The way you are doing it is adding extra processing because

```
 var $newbtncontainer = $("<div class='dt-buttons'></div>");
```

by itself creates a whole dom object then you append and prepend a whole dom object to the other controls.   I use the preInt.dt to append stuff as well with no performance issues.

Comment: That does make sense but when I tried it, the `a.buttons-colvis` and `#tblDateRange` elements are no longer visible at the top of the table. As opposed to the way I was appending originally which they were. Can you think of any reason for that?  It seems that they don't have space in `<div class='dt-buttons'>` to fit there so it only displays the table's show entries dropdown and search input.

Comment: is that what you are tying to do?  Place the built in buttons at the top?  If that is the case, take a look at thishttps://datatables.net/reference/option/dom and this https://datatables.net/reference/button/colvis.

Comment: If that is not the case then I am confused